# How to fix incorrect date and time values from Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, excelpackage

I am using `EPPlus excelpackage` with `c#` to get values from a `spreadsheet`. The spreadsheet has two separate columns `Date` and `Time`. The issue is the date value is `2/4/2020` but it returns as `2/4/2020 12:00:00 AM`. The time value is `12:21 AM` but it returns `12/30/1899 12:21:00 PM`. My desired result is to return the values as they are in the `spreadsheet`. I am not clear on why this is happening or how to fix the issue for my needs.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fs))
    {
        ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = package.Workbook;
        ExcelWorksheet ws = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
        int rowCount = 0;
        rowCount = ws.Dimension.End.Row;

        for (int r = 2; r <= rowCount; r++)
        {
            string status = ws.Cells[r, 11].Value?.ToString();
            string deliveredDate = ws.Cells[r, 15].Value?.ToString();
            string deliveredTime = ws.Cells[r, 17].Value?.ToString();
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: THere's nothing wrong. Excel stores dates as OADate values - essentially doubles with a specific meaning. Epplus understands OADates and will store `DateTime` values as OADates. How dates or times appear depends on the cell's *style*. If you modify the string, you break the date. *Don't* touch the value, modify the cell style instead

Comment: I am not clear on your suggestion. If you mean modify the cell style in the spreadsheet, I don't have permissions to do that. Should I parse out the values I need?

Comment: Use eg `ws.Cells[r, 11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";` or `ws.Cells[r, 11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";` to display the value as a date only. `hh:mm` for time, etc

Comment: You're already trying to modify the spreadsheet. The problem is the *wrong* style. You have to fix it. There's nothing wrong with the value, the problem is the *style*.

Comment: The [DateTime.ToOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToOADate) docs explain what an OADate is, end explains that the base is actually Dec 30, 1899. As a result, if a time value is formatted as a *date*, it will appear as `12/30/1899 12:21:00 PM`

Comment: Explanations by  Panagiotis Kanavos and Christopher were very helpful. Applying your example solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal mixup between the **actuall value** and **2 string representations** of said value. Thise happen especially with DateTime values.

> The issue is the date value is "2/4/2020" but it returns as "2/4/2020 12:00:00 AM"

Dates on their own do not really work. For decades now, we always have DateTimes. Date and Time as seperate types? Largely dropped. It is one of those things that are hard to explain, but become evident once you run into the underlying issue.

As no specific Time was given during input a default was asumed - 00:00:00 or 12 AM. Then the cell was set up to only display the "Date" part. Something equating to "2/4/2020 12:00:00 AM" is really what **is** there. The Display Engine called Microsoft Excel (or whatever you use) simply was told not to show that part via the Cell Formating.